# Como exibir em um Label o resultado de 2 outros Labels no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estou criando o seguinte programa de orçamentos com Python e Tkinter.

```
#  Copyright (c) Todos os Direitos Reservados a Daniel Heringer
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_MONETARY, locale= 'PT-BR')

from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry
janela = Tk ( )
ha = 0
valor = 0
comb = 0
dist = 0
pl = 0
gastos2 = 0

#Calculo do Valor da Medição

def alqueire_click():
    global valor
    medida = float ( ed.get ( ) )
    hb = medida
    lb["text"] = (f'{hb * 4.84:.2f}')
    ha = hb * 4.84
    if ha > 500:
        valor = 33.5 * ha
    if ha < 500:
        valor = 33.5 * ha
    if ha < 400:
        valor = 33.61 * ha
    if ha < 350:
        valor = 34 * ha
    if ha < 300:
        valor = 34.4 * ha
    if ha < 250:
        valor = 37 * ha
    if ha < 200:
        valor = 40.62 * ha
    if ha < 160:
        valor = 46.66 * ha
    if ha < 120:
        valor = 58.75 * ha
    if ha < 80:
        valor = 60 * ha
    if ha < 70:
        valor = 61.66 * ha
    if ha < 60:
        valor = 64 * ha
    if ha < 50:
        valor = 67.5 * ha
    if ha < 40:
        valor = 73.33 * ha
    if ha < 30:
        valor = 85 * ha
    if ha < 20:
        valor = 109 * ha
    if ha < 10:
        valor = 150 * ha
    if ha < 5:
        valor = 800
    if ha < 2:
        valor = 700
    if ha < 1:
        valor = 600
    valorreal = locale.currency(valor, grouping=True)
    lb2["text"] = (valorreal)

def Hectares_click():
    medida = float ( ed.get ( ) )
    hb = medida
    lb["text"] = (f'{hb:.2f}')
    ha = hb
    if ha > 500:
        valor = 33.5 * ha
    if ha < 500:
        valor = 33.5 * ha
    if ha < 400:
        valor = 33.61 * ha
    if ha < 350:
        valor = 34 * ha
    if ha < 300:
        valor = 34.4 * ha
    if ha < 250:
        valor = 37 * ha
    if ha < 200:
        valor = 40.62 * ha
    if ha < 160:
        valor = 46.66 * ha
    if ha < 120:
        valor = 58.75 * ha
    if ha < 80:
        valor = 60 * ha
    if ha < 70:
        valor = 61.66 * ha
    if ha < 60:
        valor = 64 * ha
    if ha < 50:
        valor = 67.5 * ha
    if ha < 40:
        valor = 73.33 * ha
    if ha < 30:
        valor = 85 * ha
    if ha < 20:
        valor = 109 * ha
    if ha < 10:
        valor = 150 * ha
    if ha < 5:
        valor = 800
    if ha < 2:
        valor = 700
    if ha < 1:
        valor = 600
    lb2["text"] = (f"{valor:.2f}")

def Litros_click():
    medida = float ( ed.get ( ) )
    hb = medida
    lb["text"] = (f'{hb * 0.0605:.2f}')
    ha = hb * 0.0605
    if ha > 500:
        valor = 33.5 * ha
    if ha < 500:
        valor = 33.5 * ha
    if ha < 400:
        valor = 33.61 * ha
    if ha < 350:
        valor = 34 * ha
    if ha < 300:
        valor = 34.4 * ha
    if ha < 250:
        valor = 37 * ha
    if ha < 200:
        valor = 40.62 * ha
    if ha < 160:
        valor = 46.66 * ha
    if ha < 120:
        valor = 58.75 * ha
    if ha < 80:
        valor = 60 * ha
    if ha < 70:
        valor = 61.66 * ha
    if ha < 60:
        valor = 64 * ha
    if ha < 50:
        valor = 67.5 * ha
    if ha < 40:
        valor = 73.33 * ha
    if ha < 30:
        valor = 85 * ha
    if ha < 20:
        valor = 109 * ha
    if ha < 10:
        valor = 150 * ha
    if ha < 5:
        valor = 800
    if ha < 2:
        valor = 700
    if ha < 1:
        valor = 600
    lb2["text"] = (f"{valor:.2f}")

def MetrosQ_click():
    medida = float ( ed.get ( ) )
    hb = medida
    lb["text"] = (f'{hb / 10000:.2f}')
    ha = hb / 10000
    if ha > 500:
        valor = 33.5 * ha
    if ha < 500:
        valor = 33.5 * ha
    if ha < 400:
        valor = 33.61 * ha
    if ha < 350:
        valor = 34 * ha
    if ha < 300:
        valor = 34.4 * ha
    if ha < 250:
        valor = 37 * ha
    if ha < 200:
        valor = 40.62 * ha
    if ha < 160:
        valor = 46.66 * ha
    if ha < 120:
        valor = 58.75 * ha
    if ha < 80:
        valor = 60 * ha
    if ha < 70:
        valor = 61.66 * ha
    if ha < 60:
        valor = 64 * ha
    if ha < 50:
        valor = 67.5 * ha
    if ha < 40:
        valor = 73.33 * ha
    if ha < 30:
        valor = 85 * ha
    if ha < 20:
        valor = 109 * ha
    if ha < 10:
        valor = 150 * ha
    if ha < 5:
        valor = 800
    if ha < 2:
        valor = 700
    if ha < 1:
        valor = 600
    lb2["text"] = (f"{valor:.2f}")

def gastos_click():
    comb = float ( lb3.get ( ) )
    dist = float ( lb4.get ( ) )
    pl = float( lb5.get ( ) )
    gastos2 = (pl / dist) * comb
    lb6["text"] = (f"{gastos2:.2f}")




ed = Entry ( janela )
ed.place ( x=130, y = 60)
ed.config( width="25", borderwidth="2", justify="center")

ed1 = Label (janela, text="Insira a Área", font="Arial 12 bold", foreground="#aaaa7f")
ed1.place ( x=25, y=57 )
ed1.config(bg="#3b3b3b")

bl = Button ( janela, width=20, text="Alqueires", command=alqueire_click)
bl.place ( x=50, y=450 )

b2 = Button ( janela, width=20, text="Hectares", command=Hectares_click)
b2.place ( x=220, y=450 )

b3 = Button ( janela, width=20, text="Litros", command=Litros_click)
b3.place ( x=50, y=500 )

b4 = Button ( janela, width=20, text="Metros Quadrados", command=MetrosQ_click)
b4.place ( x=220, y=500 )

lb = Label ( janela )
lb.place ( x=130, y=180 )
lb.config(background="#aaaa7f", relief="sunken", font="Arial 12 bold", width="15")

lbv = Label (janela, text="Hectares", font="Arial 12 bold", foreground="#aaaa7f")
lbv.place ( x=50, y=180 )
lbv.config(bg="#3b3b3b")

lb2 = Label (janela)
lb2.place (x=130, y=150)
lb2.config(background="#aaaa7f", relief="sunken", font="Arial 12 bold", width="15")

lbv2 = Label (janela, text="Valor", font="Arial 12 bold", foreground="#aaaa7f")
lbv2.place ( x=80, y=150 )
lbv2.config(bg="#3b3b3b")

lb3 = Entry (janela)
lb3.place (x=130, y=220)
lb3.config( width="25", borderwidth="2", justify="center")

#Gasto Combustivel

lbv3 = Label (janela, text="Combustivel", font="Arial 12 bold", foreground="#aaaa7f")
lbv3.place ( x=20, y=220 )
lbv3.config(bg="#3b3b3b")

lb4 = Entry (janela)
lb4.place (x=130, y=250)
lb4.config( width="25", borderwidth="2", justify="center")

lbv4 = Label (janela, text="Consumo", font="Arial 12 bold", foreground="#aaaa7f")
lbv4.place ( x=40, y=250 )
lbv4.config(bg="#3b3b3b")

lb5 = Entry (janela)
lb5.place (x=130, y=280)
lb5.config( width="25", borderwidth="2", justify="center")

lbv5 = Label (janela, text="Distância", font="Arial 12 bold", foreground="#aaaa7f")
lbv5.place ( x=40, y=280 )
lbv5.config(bg="#3b3b3b")

lb6 = Label (janela)
lb6.place (x=130, y=310)
lb6.config(background="#852a2a", relief="sunken", font="Arial 12 bold", width="15")

lbv6 = Label (janela, text="Gasto Comb.", font="Arial 12 bold", foreground="#aaaa7f")
lbv6.place ( x=20, y=310 )
lbv6.config(bg="#3b3b3b")

b5 = Button ( janela, width=20, text="Calcular Gastos", command=gastos_click)
b5.place ( x=133, y=340 )

# Lucro Liquído
lucroliquido = Label (janela, text="Lucro Liquído", font="Arial 12 bold", foreground="#aaaa7f")
lucroliquido.place ( x=400, y=310 )
lucroliquido.config(bg="#3b3b3b")

lucroliquidovalor = Label (janela)
lucroliquidovalor.place (x=520, y=310)
lucroliquidovalor.config(background="#8AAB32", relief="sunken", font="Arial 12 bold", width="15")



janela.title ( "Orçamento de Agrimensura" )
janela.geometry ( "1360x768" )
janela.config(bg="#3b3b3b")
janela.mainloop ( )
```

E no Label do Lucro Liquido eu gostaria de pegar o resultado dos Labels de Valor e gastos subtrair eles para chegar a um resultado de lucro liquido. Porém não estou conseguindo fazer o ele exibir esse resultado. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está fazendo esse projeto apenas com funções? Recomendo fazer com POO, criando classe e usando um objeto de instância (**self**) para poder trabalhar com os objetos de outros métodos. Acessar objetos usando apenas funções, não tem como nesse caso.

Comment: Eu mudei já , fiz a interface agora toda em Qt Designer e estou apenas dando funções aos botões, 
veja : https://github.com/danielheringers/pyqttest/blob/master/test

Já estão prontos os checkbox, combo box e gerar orçamento, falta agora saber como pegar todas as informações incluindo nomes e cpf e gerar um arquivo de orçamento imprimivel.